# Instance Deploy fails when using LVM

Tags: cloud-automation-manager

When I provision a single VM where the golden image has an LVM configuration inside, we get a failure:

```
    * vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_1: 1 error(s) occurred:

    * vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_1: Customization of the guest 
    operating system 'ubuntu64Guest' is not supported in this 
    configuration. Microsoft Vista (TM) and Linux guests with Logical
    Volume Manager are supported only for recent ESX host and VMware
    Tools versions. Refer to vCenter documentation for supported 
    configurations.
```

This seems to be a message returned from Vmware but we are not sure what to do.  Why did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error returned is a VSphere generic error message, not related to LVM specifically. The real error is caused by either:

1. VMware Tools not being installed (guest OS customizations require
   VMware Tools)
2. Unsupported guest OS. A list of compatible operating systems can be found [here](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/programs/guestOS/guest-os-customization-matrix.pdf)

Please make sure that you have VMware Tools installed in your template and that the guest OS is on the list of supported operating systems.

In order to skip the customization step for unsupported operating systems, use the `skip_customization` argument on the virtual machine resource.